# Loading iframe.src runs all JavaScript in the JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My app runs inside an iframe in a wrapper page.  When the wrapper page loads, the source for the iframe is set like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var frameSrc = 'myApp.jsp';
  $(document).ready(function() {
    loadFrame(frameSrc);
    $("#iFrm").height($(window).height() - 175);
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        $("#iFrm").height($(window).height() - 175);
        return false;
    });
    $("#adminLink").click(function(){
        frameSrc = 'myAdmin.jsp';
        loadFrame(frameSrc);
    });
    return false;
  });
  
  function loadFrame(src){
      $("#iFrm").attr('src', src);
  }
  </script>
```

And this loads and runs just fine, but then I've got the admin link on the page that is intended to load a different page into the iframe and it has an event handler inside the `document.ready` function.

The issue that I'm encountering is that the myAdmin.jsp is loading and then the original document.ready script, in the wrapper page, is running again - completely with the original frameSrc value.  It seems as though by changing the iframe source, it's triggering a reload of the entire wrapper page and the original iframe source.  Has anyone seen this?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this question while working through various possible solutions.  The problem turned out to have to do with *adminLink*.  The *href* value was empty, which appears to have directed the browser to reload the current page (the wrapper).  When I put *javascript: return false;* in the *href* my issue resolved.

```
<a id="adminLink" href="">Administration</a>
```

vs

```
<a id="adminLink" href="javascript:return false;">Administration</a>
```